# Get 2 variables from tables which are connected not directly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables:

```
Customer = {id,firstname,last name,street,city}
Invoice = {id, customerid, total}
Item = {invoiceid, item, productid, quantity, cost}
Product = {id, name, price}
```

I would like to get the first name of the customer and the list of products what he bought.

I have created an sql code:

```
select customer.firstname, product.name from product
inner join item on item.productid = product.id
inner join invoice on invoice.id=item.invoiceid
inner join customer on customer.id=invoice.customerid
where customer.id=24
```

the customer.id is 24, because on this id I should get only 3 items' name.
Unfortunately, I am getting multiplication of these items.

What should I repair in my query?

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting multiplication of these items.

That is how relational databases work when you ask for a join. You get a [*Cartesian Product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) of the matching records.

However, MySQL has a facility that lets you put multiple values into a single field - it's called [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html):

```
SELECT
    customer.firstname
,   GROUP_CONCAT(product.name SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM product
INNER JOIN item ON item.productid = product.id
INNER JOIN invoice ON invoice.id=item.invoiceid
INNER JOIN customer ON customer.id=invoice.customerid
WHERE customer.id=24
GROUP BY customer.id
```

Note the use of `GROUP BY`, which "merges" all rows for the same customer id into a single group, on which `GROUP_CONCAT` operates.

Comment: how about solving this problem in sql? I can't use group_concat in sql

Comment: @Ganjira You would need to live with multiple rows then: joining does produce more rows. Flattening them into one row is possible with aggregation, e.g. Fonding the count, but making a list requires a group_concat.